# Convert checkbox true value to checked symbol

Tags: lightning-datatable, datatable

Hi all I am working on a lwc datatable and I have placed a checkbox named Ischecked

[image]

It currently displays the true/false value in the datatable. Is there some way instead of this true value I can obtain a ticked symbol in the lwc component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have set the column type as text and passing the boolean value to it, which will display as literals 'true' or 'false'. So, assuming your column name is 'IsChecked', the column should be defined in LWC as follows:

```
{ label: 'IsChecked', fieldName: 'IsChecked', type: 'Boolean' }
```

This will make the column get rendered with checkbox, instead of text.

Official reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) under '*Formatting with Data Types*' section

> Additionally, specify type: 'boolean' if you're passing in a boolean
> value to a column to display a checkmark for a true value. Passing in
> a boolean value to a column of text type displays the value as true or
> false.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the data type of the column content in the type attribute. type can be set as "boolean" to get the check symbol.

```
boolean Displays the icon utility:check if the value is true, and a blank value otherwise.
```

Documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation